# Ao inserir um registro na pag1, atualizar a pag2

Tags: php, mysql, atualização

Bom Dia.
Esta é uma dúvida conceitual. Nunca precisei disso, então não sei se funciona.

Imaginem a seguinte situação:
Tenho um script A, onde eu insiro informações no banco de dados. Este script esta funcionando 100%.

Tenho um script B, onde eu fico monitorando as informações inseridas no banco de dados. Eu coloquei um refresh a cada 10 segundos, para de 10 em 10 segundos atualizar as informações inseridas através do script A.

O problema em questão é o seguinte. Eu gostaria de não precisar ter este Refresh no script B, sendo que toda vez que o script A inserisse um registro no BD, o script B fosse atualizado automaticamente. Não precisa nem ser via ajax, pode ser via refresh da pagina inteira mesmo.

Talvez para ajudar na visualização do problema, vou falar a aplicação da situação.
Tenho um restaurante onde os atendentes ficam pelo celular, tirando os pedidos na mesa (SCRIPT A). Na cozinha, tenho um monitor onde fica atualizando a cada 20 segundos (SCRIPT B) os itens pedidos no salão do restaurante.

A questão é que não quero ficar atualizando a cada 20 segundos pois tem horários em que o restaurante tem um ritmo bem tranquilo e isso geraria consumo de sistema desnecessário (consumo de banda, link, performance do sistema, etc.. etc.. etc..)

Será que isso é possível?

Comment: Talvez criando um arquivo no servidor quando o script A for chamado. A página da cozinha ficaria verificando se um novo arquivo existe, e caso SIM, faria um refresh no script B. Claro que isso iria custar requisições ao servidor de segundos em segundos, mas em contrapartida pouparia requisições desnecessárias ao BD. Talvez haja algo mais eficiente e melhor a menor custo. Creio que apenas uma verificação se um arquivo existe não seria tão oneroso ao sistema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer o que você deseja, você precisa criar uma conexão WebSocket.

O WebSocket faz uma conexão entre um cliente (de um navegador da Web) para um servidor. Uma vez que uma conexão WebSocket é estabelecida, ela permanece aberta até o cliente ou o servidor decidir fecha-la. Com esta conexão aberta, o cliente ou o servidor podem enviar uma mensagem a qualquer momento para o outro. Isso torna a comunicação na web inteiramente dirigida por eventos, e não exclusivamente pelo usuário.

Em outras palavras, a comunicação se torna dinâmica e os dados consumidos serão feitos a partir do eventos de cliques pelos usuários ou algum tipo de mudança no estado do servidor que ficará "escutando" todas as conexões. Sem a necessidade de loops no lado do cliente ou "refresh" de tempos em tempos.

Então, no seu caso, seria algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O atendente envia a informação ao servidor, que muda seu estado, e envia a nova informação para o "gerente" da cozinha que é notificado quase instantaneamente. Pois assim como o atendente, o gerente também tem uma conexão WebSocket.

Links úteis:

[Tutorial Chat com WebSocket e PHP](http://rafaelcouto.com.br/chat-simples-utilizando-websocket-vue-js-e-php/)

[Demonstração](http://socketo.me/demo)

Tem muitas informações sobre isso no google.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Excelente. Obrigado.

Comment: Tranquilo @NovatodaWeb =)